# Cant Use Tkinter module in setuptools for python2

Tags: python, tkinter, setuptools

I have used module for Tkinter in python2 app.
But don't know how to put it as install requirements in setup.py.
My setup.py file has following modules

```
install_requires=[
    'pushbullet.py',
    'tweepy',
    'beautifulsoup4',
    'requests',
    'yweather'
],
```

i want to include Tkinter (python-tk), but I am not able to do so.

Comment: Please don't vote to close - there is enough information in the short question for people with knowledge on the tags to come up with an answer. (though, I imagine, not one the O.P. will like)

Comment: How to put *what* as install requirements? `Tkinter` is part of the standard library.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : i have made a python app for linux. I have put up
<code>
install_requires=[
          'pushbullet.py',
          'tweepy',
          'beautifulsoup4',
          'requests',
          'yweather'
      ],
</code>

I want to include Tkinter (python-tk) module too similarly. But could not find any way to do so. If you could help.

Comment: Tkinter does not install with python by default on Ubuntu